# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in file при попытке использовать try

Tags: php

ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/viptop/l/u/c/luckydropcsgo/public_html/steamauth/steamauth.php on line 11

11 строка содержит:

```
{ try }
```

в чём ошибка?

Comment: А в чем вопрос то?

Comment: @Flowneee а разве непонятно? Вопрос - где ошибка и как исправить?))

Comment: я не понимаю что тут может быть не так.

Comment: @user200670 да не. Всё верно. Вам кажется. Именно так все приложения и работают

Comment: после оператора `try`, вроде бы, [должен идти блок](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php): `try { }`.

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция `try` в полном, компилируемом виде, должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
try
{
    // код, который может выбросить исключение
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //$e - экземпляр класса Exception
    // или его наследника, содержащие инфу об ошибке
    //коя была выброшена в ходе выполнения кода из блока try
}
finally
{
    //код тут выполнится вне зависимости о того, было ли брошено исключение
   //в ходе выполнения кода из блока try
}
```

У вас же всего одна скобка `}` после `try`. Оттого и ошибка.